# Why is that we see executed javascript when the server returns a JSON?

Tags: html, json, web, single-page-application

I currently understand the basics of HTTP (web browsers send mostly GET or POST requests, server responds)

I know that the server can return a full HTML document, ready to be viewed in a web browser

I know that the server can return just JSON-encoded data

I understand that if the server returns a bare bones html document, with only the head and an empty body, that body can be filled by javascript code supplied by other different endpoint (if you link that js code in a script element in the head)

I do not understand how can we see anything other than the json data when the api only returns json data.

Can an single api endpoint respond with both JSON data and a bare bones html?

Answer (score 0):

You can receive only the particular type like html,json,jpg etc.you cant get the combination in single api.